# Как сделать этот table в html?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать эту таблицу используя html и css?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: Такой вид таблицы, используя только <table> не реально, можно попробовать, но сделать очень сложно. Для этого надо спользовать Bootstrap, c его класом col-md можно сделать эту таблицу. Класс делит экран на 12 частей, которые ты уже сам регулируешь. Там есть не только col-md но и другие. Посмотри Bootstrap и тебе сразу станет легче делать эту таблицу

Comment: @aleksandr barakin - ну, а с другой стороны - как человек объяснит, что нужно? - Так наглядно, по крайней мере, и нет множества уточняющих вопросов - лучше один раз увидеть.

Comment: @Coder «как человек объяснит, что нужно?» — я не знаю, что **именно** нужно автору вопроса. но попробую угадать хотя бы часть вопроса: «как создать таблицу с разным количеством строк в разных столбцах. например, в одном столбце две строки, а в другом — три».

Comment: @aleksandr barakin вариаций таких много может быть - как говорится - "чтобы задать правильно вопрос, нужно знать 80% ответа" - думается, что в отсутствии таких знаний лучше действительно наглядно - имхо, конечно.

Comment: @Coder, но этот вопрос (и, главное, ответ на него) будет абсолютно бесполезен **всем** (ну, кроме автора вопроса, и то не факт): его просто невозможно будет найти — нет никаких ключевых слов, отличающих его от тысяч и тысяч вопросов «про таблицы в html». поэтому картинку можно приложить **как дополнение** к вопросу, но не как его замену.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin - наверное, Вы правы - может, автор в текстовой форме дополнит вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

```css
.main {
background: black
}

.first, .second {
width: 330px;
height: 330px;
background: #334867;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.5em;
border: 5px solid white;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

.first {
border-right: 0px;
margin-right: -3px
}
.second {
border-left: 0px;
margin-left: -3px
}
```

```html
<table class="main">
  <tr><td>
    <table class="first" border=collapsed>
     <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>3</td>
       <td>4</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</td>
<td>
  <table  class="second" border=collapsed>
    <tr>
     <td>5</td>
     <td>6</td>
     <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>8</td>
     <td>9</td>
     <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>11</td>
     <td>12</td>
     <td>13</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Или такой вариант:

```css
.main {
background:black;
padding: 7px
}

:root {
 --main-border: 5px solid white;
}

.main-td1, .main-td2 {
border-top: var(--main-border);
border-bottom: var(--main-border);
}
.main-td1 {
border-left: var(--main-border);
}
.main-td2 {
border-right: var(--main-border);
}

.first, .second {
width: 330px;
height: 330px;
background: #334867;
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.5em;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="main" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <tr><td class="main-td1">
<table class="first" border=collapsed cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</td>
<td class="main-td2">
  <table  class="second" border=collapsed cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
 <td>5</td>
 <td>6</td>
 <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>8</td>
 <td>9</td>
 <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>11</td>
 <td>12</td>
 <td>13</td>
</tr>
   </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```